# Assertion Error when compiling LSTM with Keras

Tags: python, theano, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following code:

```
max_features = 5000
maxlen = 140
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128)) 
model.add(LSTM(128, activation = 'sigmoid', inner_activation =  'hard_sigmoid', return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dense(input_dim = 128, output_dim = 2, activation = 'softmax'))

optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-8)
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizer)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 64, nb_epoch = 10, verbose = 2)

y_test_pred = model.predict_classes(x_test)
```

But everytime I run it, I get an error at the line

```
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizer)
```

which states:

```
 AssertionError: The number of inputs given to the inner function of scan does not match the number of inputs given to scan.
```

Does anyone know what that means?

Comment: I have fixed this problem, turns out it has something to do with an outdated Theano version. So if you are experiencing this problem, update your theano module!

Answer (score 0):

*Answer by OP:*

I have fixed this problem, turns out it has something to do with an outdated Theano version. So if you are experiencing this problem, update your theano module!